# How can i access junction table in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Good evenings,fine sirs. I am working with Sequelize with NodeJS. I created Many-to-many association between two table User and Project.

```
//This is Project Model

const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Project extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { User, Issue } = models;

      this.belongsToMany(User, {
        as: "project_users",
        foreignKey: "project_id",
        through: "projectuser",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.hasMany(Issue, {
        as: "project_issues",
        foreignKey: "project_id",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }
  Project.init(
    {
      project_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      projectname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      projecturl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Project",
    }
  );
  return Project;
};

//This is User Model


const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { Commet, Project, Issue } = models;

      this.hasMany(Commet, {
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        as: "user_commets",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.belongsToMany(Project, {
        as: "project_user",
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        through: "projectuser",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.belongsToMany(Issue, {
        as: "user_issues",
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        through: "issueuser",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          roleValidator(role) {
            let rolet = role.toLowerCase();

            if (roles[rolet] === undefined) {
              throw new Error("Invalid Role");
            }
          },
        },
      },
      username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      usersurname: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      avatarURL: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          passwordValidator(password) {
            if (password.length <= 5) {
              throw new Error("Cannot be less than 5 characters");
            }
          },
        },
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        validate: { isEmail: true },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

My question may be silly but, do i need to create junction table manually to access it from my code or is there any way to access it without creating it? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It's better to define it explicitly as a model. That way you'll be able to have fine-grained control over it and even add additional columns there.